# Trying to sleep but seeing things

Tags: jinn

While I’m trying to sleep I often think that a jinn inside my house is able to take me somewhere and show me things. While I’m trying to sleep I often see things like I’m actually there. I see what I believe is the inside of my house and I can see the door open and close as well as someone sitting on my down stairs couch. I also see people up stairs sitting on my couch. Recently i believe I was taken inside a room and what looked to me like a Kurdish jinn. I believe this because I’m Kurdish and the girl looked Kurdish and she just walked up and I saw her. I just saw once something I thought looked scary in the back. Not only this I often hear doors opening and closing while trying to sleep and I hear voices saying very very random things. I think there’s some jinns inside my house but I think they’re good jinns because after days of going on YouTube and trying to remove them I believe they’re still here. The reason is because they keep showing me things at night while trying to sleep. I’m not fully asleep yet. I’m trying to sleep. Another thing that happened was I felt someone’s finger scratching my thigh. Something else that happens is that Im sometimes being feed something and I cannot but help to eat it and know when to eat it for some reason. While this is happening I know it’s not normal for this to happen so I immediately start thinking it’s a jinn but can’t stop it. I’ll even listen to YouTube at night to remove jinn from my body but it’ll still happen. Another one I can see is like dark images that I can barley make out and tell know what it exactly is. For example someone with their head sideways, the outside of a house, someone with a long very skinny neck with a piece of paper in its hand, a big ufo sphere space ship like it it’s huge, sometimes I see what I think looks like the devil with two horns on its head and sitting criss crossed holding the peace sign I see sometimes of things I look up online when looking up things like jinns on the internet and seeing what they look like and I often see that but it’s very very dark and I can barley tell what it is some of it I’m sure of what it is. I think it’s just a bunch of kid jinns either just showing me stuff or they’re just doing it cause they’re kids the reason being is I’ve seen old looking jinns sitting on my couch down stairs. It seems harmless but I’m worried about what this is. I’ve never heard of this before and not able to find something similar while trying to look it up. I’ve tried listening to Surah Al baqarah every night but still happening. Someone told me that they’re not allowed to touch people. Someone said once they start touching me I should expect disaster to happen quickly so I’m worried about it. He also said they’re because they either want something from me or I’m the greatest scholar of my time ( which I’m not, not even a scholar either) he said it has been reported by them. I’m not sure what to do now.

Answer (score 0):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you and your family are doing well. Regarding your question there are two things that needs to be done whenever we face a health issue, mental issue or spiritual issue.

1. Stop the incoming harm (bad food, bad thoughts, etc.)
2. Cure / Heal the damage (medicine, reading Quraan, dhikr , etc.)
3. Prevention (good food, good thoughts , protection with Quraan)

So in your case the first recommendation is to block the incoming traffic. For you to do that stop as many sins as you are doing. If you are in bad company stay away. If you are wearing dirty clothes make sure they are clean. Then for the curing and preventative part after fajr prayer or before sunrise read

- Surah Ikhlaas (Chapter 112) three times
- Surah Falaq (Chapter 113) three times
- Surah Naas (Chapter 114) three times

You will read again after Asr prayer as well or sometime in the evening before nightfall. Furthermore, before sleeping and while in bed read Ayatul Kursi (Chapter 2 , Verse 255) once.

Moreover, if possible try to stay in wudu throughout the day as much as possible.

Do these things and you will see the difference. But keep doing them and never let them go throughout your life. There are more things that you can do but I don't want to overburden you right now. However, if you want to hear them you may ask.

**Have a Nice Day!**

**Note #1:** If you downvote my answer, please be courteous and say why you downvoted in a comment below.

**Note #2:** This is my own personal answer that I have derived from what I have researched.